# ?How to change textarea input color to green?

Tags: html, css, web

I have got this textarea and i wonder if there is a way of changing the input color for this textarea so i can type green text on a black background:

```css
textarea{
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="htmlCode" class="1111" placeholder="HTML"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change font-color. font-size, font-family.. for placeholder with `::placeholder` pseudo-element [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder)

```css
textarea{
  background-color: black;
  color: green;
}
textarea::placeholder{
color: green;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="htmlCode" class="1111" placeholder="HTML"></textarea>
```

Comment: This works to change placeholder color but is it possible to change the color of the text i'm typing in the textarea ?

Comment: @ThespAceCompany i update answer, just add color to textarea

Comment: tnx soooo much, actually i tried it but it didnt work for me, i tried on another browser, now it works

Comment: bruh, it didnt work on chrome @ first but now it does....
Guess my pc sucks ad lags